# Oracle connection and running script in c#

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, ado.net, sqlplus

I have got the following code

```
         using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection())
          {
            con.ConnectionString = My_connection_string;               
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Scripts/call_proc.sql"));
            string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
            con.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(script, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.BindByName = true;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
```

The call_proc code is
//returns Hello

```
         set serveroutput on;
         begin
         test.tmp_test();
         end;
```

When I try to run the above code it gives me the following errors.

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 11: PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid
>   option ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:

Comment: _set serveroutput on;_ is not valid for PL/SQL.

Comment: @Sathya if i remove serveroutput on; then i get the following error. ORA-06550: line 1, column 12:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

Comment: do you really need to use a file? Could not you just use a `OracleCommand` with the procedure name? For sample: `new OracleCommand("test.temp_test", con);`

Comment: @FelipeOriani i tried this and gives me the following error. ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00801: internal error [22503]
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:

Comment: @Sathya, you need to check that your SP is compiled successfully.

Comment: @FelipeOriani i tried your suggested code and it worked. Thanks but this test.temp_test returns HEllo word. how do i access and display this value.

Comment: I anwsered your question, take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a `OracleCommand` with the procedure name For sample

Try something like this:

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection())
{
    con.ConnectionString = My_connection_string;               
    con.Open();

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("temp.tmp_test", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.BindByName = true;

    var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if (result != null)
    {
        string stringResult = result.ToString();

        // show result here
    }   

}
```

You can use `command.ExecuteScalar()` if you want to take the first column and first line, it will return an `object` instance.

You can also use a [Oracle Data Reader](http://docs.oracle.com/html/B28089_01/OracleDataReaderClass.htm) from `command.ExecuteDataReader()` if you want to read many lines and columns (very common when you want to manipulate an output from a `select` query).